# GWT Stock Watcher - Polling not Push?

Tags: gwt

In the GWT Stock Watch tutorial it seems to be polling the server every 4 seconds for new data. Is this the standard way GWT works or is it possible to use a push type technology so that when new events are raised on the server the client code gets called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the standard way GWT works. The incubator has a page [outlining how you can achieve push with GWT](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-incubator/wiki/ServerPushFAQ).

Comment: If you have Java on the server side, you can use stuff rocket-gwt (http://code.google.com/p/rocket-gwt/wiki/Comet) or cometd (http://cometdproject.dojotoolkit.org/). If you have something else (like PHP) it gets harder but it's doable - there's Ape-Project (http://www.ape-project.org/home.html) and NGiNX_HTTP_Push_Module (http://pushmodule.slact.net/). I prefer nginx's one (because you don't have to use any external js lib like mootools, you can write easily your own client side - the protocol is nice and easy), but Ape-Server is worth checking out too.

Answer (score 0):

The concept of server push (aka COMET) can be achieved using GWT. You should check out Stream Hub. It is closed source for the time being but I believe it is active. I hope they open source it :).

GWT example

http://www.stream-hub.com/demo/gwt-comet-stock-table/gwt-stock-table-demo.html

Main site

http://www.stream-hub.com/